# After Flush Catalog Images Cache order email product image not showing

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, email

Am using **Magento 1.8** after Flush Catalog Images Cache order email product image not showing for `simple product` but image show for `configurable product`. Following email 
[image]

And this my code in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

```
if ($_item->getProductType() !== Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
    $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                       ->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());  
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($parentIds[0]);
} else {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($_item->getProductId());  
}


<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

How can I fix this error...? ANd thanks in advance